# How to execute some code after all retries are exhausted in spring batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-retry

I have set the maximum number of retry as 3. I have added only RemoteAccessException as retry-able exception. What I want to do, is to change the state of some of the entities to error and persist them to database after all retries are exhausted. All of this I am doing in writer step. I have implemented ItemWriteListener and when RemoteAccessException occurs, it does go to onWriteError method, where I have written this state changing logic.But when I check the database after all execution is done, I see that the state is not changed at all.

My question is, exactly what is happening in this case? After 3 retries, does the entire step rollbacks, as the exception is still there and so nothing is changed in database? And also, I do need to change the states to error. Is there some way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer of this. In my case, what was happening -  RetryExhaustedException was being thrown after 3 retries. As it is stated in the Spring Retry docs, any enclosing transaction will be rolled back in this case.

From spring docs(https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/retry.html)-

> After a callback fails the RetryTemplate has to make a call to the RetryPolicy to ask it to update its state (which will be stored in the RetryContext), and then it asks the policy if another attempt can be made. If another attempt cannot be made (e.g. a limit is reached or a timeout is detected) then the policy is also responsible for handling the exhausted state. Simple implementations will just throw RetryExhaustedException which will cause any enclosing transaction to be rolled back. More sophisticated implementations might attempt to take some recovery action, in which case the transaction can remain intact.

For the case where I need to change the states to error, I have asked a similar question and found the answer -
[Is there any way to persist some data in database after an exception occurs in ItemWriter in spring batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791072/is-there-any-way-to-persist-some-data-in-database-after-an-exception-occurs-in-i)