# Is there any way to persist some data in database after an exception occurs in ItemWriter in spring batch?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I want to persist some data after an exception occurs in ItemWriter step. But if I am not incorrect, in this case a rollback would happen and so this persisting logic won't work.Is there any way to achieve this?

Right now, I am implementing itemWriteListener and all the persisting logic is written inside onWriteError method. This logic only concerns to change state of some entities to error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a separate connection that does not participate in the transaction.  For example, inject a `DataSource` into your listener and construct your own `JdbcTemplate` with an independent connection.  By doing that, the writes should not be rolled back.

Comment: Thank you Micheal for the answer. I just want to clarify one thing. If I mark the onWriteError method with @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)...would this work as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you mark the `onWriteError` method with

```java
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

...would this work as well?